# How To Chage Bootstrap 4 Default Radio Button Color When It Is Clicked?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here I have boostrap4 radio button which is when clicked have blue background color.
Now, what I am trying to do is to change the background color of radio button to green that is when radio button is clicked it should change it's color to green.

Below is my radio button

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">A. Option1
    </label>
</div>
```

Below is my css

```
 .form-check .form-check-input:checked {
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the custom classes with the below CSS:

**Sample Code:**

```css
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #7B1FA2;
}

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label.red::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-check">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="opt1" name="optradio" class="custom-control-input" value="A. Option1">
      <label class="custom-control-label red" for="opt1">A. Option1</label>
  </div>
</div>
```